# How to list all Sub Groups in a column, using GROUP BY and COUNT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, categories

I am struggling with displaying all of the sub-groups for my second column because most have null values. I want to be able to show all of the rows regardless of the value being null or not. I also want to be able to display all of my content for my first column.

Currently I have:

```
dmd.type       dmd.locstatus   Count()      SUM(dmd.balance)
loc            active          3              -70860.33
loc            cancelled       1                   0.00
locmtg         active          2             -614268.02
locmtg         approved        1                   0.00
```

But I want to have:

```
dmd.type       dmd.locstatus   Count()      SUM(dmd.balance)
loc            active          3              -70860.33
               approved        0                   0.00
               cancelled       1                   0.00
               pending         0                   0.00
               rejected        0                   0.00
locmtg         active          2             -614268.02
               approved        1                   0.00
               cancelled       0                   0.00
               pending         0                   0.00
               rejected        0                   0.00
loc5k          active          0                   0.00
               approved        0                   0.00
               cancelled       0                   0.00
               pending         0                   0.00
               rejected        0                   0.00
```

My current code:

```
SELECT   dmd.type, dmd.locstatus, COUNT(cust.no_) AS Count, SUM(dmd.balance)
FROM     dmd INNER JOIN
         cust ON dmd.rowno_custdmd_cust = cust.rowno
WHERE    (dmd.type LIKE 'loc%') 
GROUP BY dmd.type, dmd.locstatus
ORDER BY dmd.type, dmd.locstatus
```

Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: Does the column `dmd.locstatus` have a foreign key to another table, e.g. table `locstatus` ? If so you could use a `cross join locstatus` to get what you want. Also make the inner join to cust an `outer join cust`, so it also displays when there are no values in `cust`

Comment: Unfortunately `locstatus` belongs strictly to the `dmd` table. The `outer join cust` does not appear to work on my SQL server. Thank you though @avk

Comment: okay that's too bad, but you could create a subquery containing all the three types using `select 'active' as locstatus from dual union select 'approved' from dual union...` and then cross join this subquery `on dmd.locstatus = <subquery.locstatus>`

Answer (score 1):

To approach this, generate all the rows using a `cross join`.  Then use `left join` to bring in the rows with values:

```
SELECT t.type, l.locstatus, COUNT(cust.no_) AS Count, SUM(dmd.balance)
FROM (select distinct dmd.type from dmd where dmd.type LIKE 'loc%') t CROSS JOIN
     (select distinct dmd.locstatus from dmd) l LEFT JOIN
     dmd
     ON dmd.type = t.type and dmd.locstatus = l.locstatus LEFT JOIN
     cust
     ON dmd.rowno_custdmd_cust = cust.rowno
GROUP BY t.type, l.locstatus
ORDER BY t.type, l.locstatus;
```

As for skipping values in a column, you should do that at the application layer, rather than in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Other than suppressing the repeated values (which should be done in the UI layer, *NOT* in SQL), this should work:

```
SELECT  
   dmd.type, 
   dmd.locstatus, 
   ISNULL(det.Count, 0) Count, 
   ISNULL(det.balance,0) balance
FROM     dmd
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT   d.type, d.locstatus, COUNT(cust.no_) AS Count, SUM(d.balance)
    FROM     dmd d
    INNER JOIN cust ON d.rowno_custdmd_cust = cust.rowno
    GROUP BY d.type, d.locstatus
) det 
ON dmd.type = det.type
    AND dmd.locstatus = det.locstatus
WHERE (dmd.type LIKE 'loc%') 
ORDER BY dmd.type, dmd.locstatus
```